# How to add images to ScrollView dynamically?

Tags: android

I am trying to add images to scrollview dynamically. To add images to scrollview I am using this code:

```
        LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.filesScrollerLayout);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( pub.FirstPicture ) ); // same happens with ScaleDrawable.
        iv.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE );
        sv.addView( iv ); 


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:background="#FFFF00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So I need to add images to this scrollview like this:

```
|-------------
|
|Image 1
|-------------
|
|Image 2
|-------------
|
|Image 3
|-------------
```

For this I need to change somehow content size of Scrollview ?

How this is done in Android ?

Thanks.

Comment: use a ListView. that what they're for.

Comment: also, use a fix size for the ScrollView. match_parent, most likely, and not wrap_content, as it may simply grow out of the screen

Comment: I don't want to use listView i want to use ScrollView with  buttons which would have image background.

Thanks for tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"     << this line
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>


LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout .addView(imageView);
```

Comment: which is basically what he is doing.

Comment: set the orientation of the LinearLayout to VERTICAL

Comment: that's indeed a problem in his XML

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what's happening right now? Is it running and nothing shows up?

I have a hunch that you have to set the layout params for stuff to show up. Try adding the following to your image view before adding to the Linear layout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT); 

iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
sv.addView( iv );
```